# scons: making glob play nice with a build directory

Tags: scons

I would like to build all .c files in a subdirectory. I figured I would do something like this:

`src/foo/SConscript` contains:

```
import glob;
here = Dir('.');
sourcefiles_raw = glob.glob(here.path+'/*.c');
print(sourcefiles_raw);
# print them for debugging
# ... then build them (in the process, making scons aware of dependencies)
```

`src/SConscript` contains:

```
SConscript(['foo/SConscript']);
```

`SConstruct` contains:

```
SConscript(['src/SConscript'],build_dir='build');
```

But it prints `[]`, since `glob.glob()` runs in the directory `build/foo` before scons can decide which sourcefiles need to be copied from `src/foo` to `build/foo`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

never mind, it seems you're supposed to ([RTFM](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html#lbAI)) and use scons's `Glob()` rather than `glob.glob()`.